# relation with users model (django)

Tags: django, model

when i run `makemigration` in `manage.py` i got this exception

> SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS: market.Customer.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation
> with model 'User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
> market.Customer.user: (fields.E307) The field market.Customer.user was
> declared with a lazy reference to 'market.user', but app 'market'
> doesn't provide model 'user'.

Comment: Can you share the relevant model(s), likely `Customer`?

Comment: Do you have `'django.contrib.auth'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes, i have 'django.contrib.auth' in INSTALLED_APPS